# Internet Explorer Label Link Not Working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, label, zurb-foundation

I am building a site with Zurb's Foundation framework. I have a side navigation that is working fine in every browser except IE (of course). In IE, if you try to click a sidebar link, it does not work if you try to click the text. If you click the box around the text or the icon, it works. I'm guessing this has something to do with the weird way that IE treats `<label>` tags, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Anyone know what I should do to get the links working?

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/regularmegs/j7ezudra/3/)

```
<!-- Sidebar Navigation -->
<div class="sidebar left clearfix">
    <div class="icon-bar vertical five-up label-right left clearfix">
      <a class="item" id="home">
        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        <label>Home</label>
      </a>
      <a class="item" id="resources">
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        <label>Resources</label>
      </a>
      <a class="item" id="reports">
        <i class="fa fa-pie-chart fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        <label>Reports</label>
      </a>
      <a class="item" id="team">
        <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        <label>Team</label>
      </a>
      <a class="item" id="support-tickets">
        <span class="notification-container">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
            <span class="notification-counter">1</span>
            <label>Support Tickets</label>
        </span>
      </a>
      <!-- These Last 2 Items to Be Displayed Only On Certain Pages as Necessary -->
      <a class="item" id="director-info">
        <i class="fa fa-shield fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        <label>Director Info</label>
      </a>
      <a class="item" id="merge-accounts">
        <i class="fa fa-compress fa-2x fa-fw"></i>
        <label>Merge Account</label>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Sidebar -->
```

I should mention that it apparently works if I remove the `<label>` tag, but then my CSS gets messed up. Wondering if there's an easier fix.

Comment: Sorry, just updated it. Seems like every time I include code in my question, people ask me for a fiddle. Guess I'll just do both from now on.

Comment: What are you using a <label> for? It seems you are incorrectly using them.  http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label

Comment: The side nav is a combination of Foundation's [Side Nav](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/sidenav.html) and [Icon Bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/icon-bar.html). In their code for the Icon Bar, they use labels and so I did too.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue using the foundation Icon Bar.

Try using pointer-events: none on your labels like so

`.item label {
    pointer-events: none;
}`

Comment: This does not fix the invalid markup but at least it works with only 3 lines of CSS code, thank you.